# Django REST Framework and combining models

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**Updated question**

I was able to get it to work and have updated the codes below. But now my question is how can the fields in `iceinfo` be edited? As it stands now it is returned as `IceInfo object` and not as editable fields. I can edit `ice_code` and `ice_maker` only.

**Old question**

I'm trying to build an API for our database. The information in the database is divided between multiple tables, all of which have the same '`Ice-code`' as their primary key.

I've been trying now for a better part of a week to combine the tables so I can from one url (`api.something.com/ice/`) be able to see a list of ice and from (`api.something.com/ice/1`) be able to see a detailed view of the ice combining information from all tables.

Seems that no matter what I try I fail to combine the tables.

Here is a rough draft of what I have so far. I would like to be able to update the fields from the front end eventually. Total number of rows per table is somewhere around 70-80k and they have more columns than the ones here but I'm just trying to make a rough working draft.

**# models.py**

```
class IceInfo(models.Model):

    ice_name = models.TextField(db_column='Ice name', blank=True, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Updated')
    ice_code = models.ForeignKey(IceList, related_name='iceinfo', db_column='Ice-code', on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Ice_Info'


class IceList(models.Model):
    ice_code = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='Ice-code', max_length=10)
    ice_maker = models.CharField(db_column='Ice Maker', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Updated')
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Ice_List'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ice_code
```

**# serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import IceList, IceInfo



class IceInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = IceInfo
        fields = '__all__'


class IceListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    iceinfo = IceInfoSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = IceList
        fields = ('ice_code', 'ice_maker', 'iceinfo')
```

**# views.py**

```
from .models import IceInfo, IceList
from .serializers import IceListSerializer
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView, RetrieveAPIView, RetrieveUpdateAPIView
from rest_framework.filters import SearchFilter, OrderingFilter


class IceList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = IceList.objects.all()
    serializer_class = IceListSerializer
    filter_backends = [SearchFilter, OrderingFilter]
    search_fields = ['ice_code', 'ice_maker', 'ice_name']
```

**Results in**

```
"results": [
        {
        "ice_code": 1,
        "iceinfo": [
        {
            ice_name": "Ice Name 1"
        }
        )
        "ice_maker": "Ice Maker 1"
        },
       {
        "ice_code": 2,
        "iceinfo": [
        {
            ice_name": "Ice Name 2"
        }
        )
        "ice_maker": "Ice Maker 2"

        },
```

Comment: Seems to me that you don't need the IceListSerializer to serializer many instances of IceInfo, just use many=True. Why do you even need IceList?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you elaborate on what you meant by just using many=True? The Ice_List and Ice_Info tables both contain many more columns so that's why both IceList and IceInfo are used.

Comment: Assuming your goal is to serializers many instances of IceInfo, what is the purpose of IceList? Or are you trying something different? If I'm right, you can do that by passing the queryset to the serializer, and give give the keyword many=True. See here:
[documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/#working-with-serializers)

Comment: I'm new to Django Rest so I was following a tutorial and it showed serializer for each model or that is how I at least understood it. My goal is to simply display the list and a detailed view of the ice_code and update it if needed. I can get it to work fine with just one table/model but keep failing when I have to include another table. Sould the `IceList` queryset be set to something like `queryset = IceListSerializer(IceList.objects.all(), many=True)`?

Comment: try something like queryset = IceInfoSerializer(IceInfo.objects.all(), many=True). If it doesn't work, let me know!

Comment: I added the updated code to bottom of the original question, it results in `object of type 'ListSerializer' has no len()` error.

Comment: I managed to get it working and have updated the original question to reflect that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your goal is to serializers many instances of IceInfo, what is the purpose of IceList? Or are you trying something different? Rest framework has no problem serialising multiple objects into a list.

You can do that by passing the queryset to the serializer, and give give the keyword many=True. See here:
[documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/#working-with-serializers)

The result would be something like
 `queryset = IceInfoSerializer(IceInfo.objects.all(), many=True)`.

About the new question, you should be able to edit them from the queryset. What have you tried so far? (You may be better of opening a new topic on the new question)

Also, the JSON you posted doesn't seem valid, can you check if you copy pasted it correctly?