# Django Rest FrameWork: Combining data from different models before sending response

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have a default user model

I created a userprofile model as shown below.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from users.utils.age_validator import MinAgeValidator
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator


class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mobile_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, unique=True, null=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="proile_image", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
        if kwargs['created']:
            user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

    post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

There is a search view written as shown below

```
class FindUser(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    search_fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name']
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FindUserSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    pagination_class = SearchLimitPagination
```

Then I defined serializers to combine data from both models.

```
class UserProfileImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('profile_image',)
        read_only_fields = ['profile_image']


class FindUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    image = UserProfileImageSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name','image')
```

The question is similar to the this([Django REST Framework and combining models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42611225/django-rest-framework-and-combining-models)). But this is not working for me. It is not giving error but a response without the profile data as shown below.

```
{
    "count": 11,
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/userprofile/finduser/?limit=5&offset=5&search=a",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [   

        {
            "id": 43,
            "username": "pikachu",
            "first_name": "",
            "last_name": ""
        },
}
```

Iam using django 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `source='userprofile'` in your serializer like this,

```
class FindUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    image = UserProfileImageSerializer(source='userprofile', read_only=True)

    .....
    .....
```

Not tested, but it should work now.

Comment: its works but when I give userprofile insead of user. I think you should change that.